# Display a textbox over a picturebox

Tags: c#, winforms

I display dynamically some images and when i hover with mouse i want to display a text box which, if case, will be displayed over all images or over some of them.

This is how i dispay images dynamically:

```
var picture = new PictureBox
                {
                    Name = "pictureBox" + contor,
                    Size = new Size(72, 72),
                    Location = new Point(x, y),
                    Image = Image.FromFile("C://Users//radul//OneDrive//Desktop//Pictures Lic//rf 72x72.png"),
                };

x += 100; 
y = (y + 100) % this.Size.Height;
picture.MouseDown += new MouseEventHandler(picture_MouseDown);
picture.MouseMove += new MouseEventHandler(picture_MouseMove);
picture.MouseUp += new MouseEventHandler(picture_MouseUp);
picture.MouseHover += new EventHandler(picture_MouseHover);
picture.MouseLeave += new EventHandler(picture_MouseLeave);

this.Controls.Add(picture);
```

and to show textbox:

```
private void picture_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e){

   tBox.Height = 100;
   tBox.Width = 400;
   tBox.Multiline = true;
   tBox.BringToFront();
   tBox.Text = detalii;
   tBox.Top = picBox.Top + 20;
   tBox.Left = picBox.Right + 20;
   this.Controls.Add(tBox);
}
```

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HUmiG.png) here is what my program displays and what i want is that textbox to be over that images.

Comment: please insert the image into the question without using 3rd party services/software

Comment: hope is allrigth  now

Comment: why not use tooltips?
they pretty much do exactly what you want without all your event handeling something linke `picture.tooltip = "Blablablabla";`

Comment: I'd recommend using a tooltip instead https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/918e32fb-b63d-4e6b-9084-76627030d463/can-i-show-a-tooltip-when-a-user-hovers-over-a-picturebox-control?forum=winforms

Comment: i did not even heard about them, that's i am not using them

Comment: when you run into common issues like this where you want to display a textbox and you have seen it 100 times in different programs beeing used you can be almost certein that there is a standard implementation that you can use.

Comment: But it seems to be suitable for what i want. I will modify my code and see what happens. Thanks

Comment: It works perfectly. I did not know about tooltip before. Thank you.

Comment: Glad we could help